# jQuery click fadeIn / fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I have a probably dumb question, but I can't figure it out on my own...

I'd like to alternatively fadeIn / fadeOut two div by cliking on a third one.

Here is a non working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/

Here is the html :

```
<div id="a"> </div>
<div id="alpha"> ALPHA </div>
<div id="beta"> BETA </div>
```

The CSS :

```
#a { width: 200px; height: 40px; line-height: 40px; background-color: red; text-align: center; }
#a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
#alpha, #beta {  width: 200px; height: 100px; margin-top: 20px; }
#alpha { background-color: blue; }
#beta { background-color: green; }
```

And js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#beta').hide();
    $('#a').click(function() {
        $('#alpha').fadeOut("slow", function() {
             $('#beta').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

I can do the first animation (fadeOut alpha, fadeIn beta), but on the second click, I'd like to do the inverse and so on...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can select the both elements and filter the visible one, `.fadeOut()` the visible one and `.fadeIn()` the hidden one.

```
var $e = $('#beta, #alpha').filter('#beta').hide().end();

$('#a').click(function() {
    $e.filter(':visible').fadeOut("slow", function() {
         $e.not(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/8/

Comment: I think this is my favourite solution.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of code I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#beta').hide();
    var el = '#alpha';
    $('#a').click(function () {
        $(el).fadeOut("slow", function () {
            el = el == '#alpha' ? '#beta' : '#alpha';
            $(el).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8LKL2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div id="a">

</div>

<div class="alpha"> ALPHA </div>
<div class="alpha">  BETA </div>
```

so you can use **classes** because IDs are unique, and you can control both instead of one by one.

Now you have two options.

**1** Use `fadeToggle` (Javascript):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#beta').hide();
    $('#a').click(function() {
        $('.alpha').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/11/)**

**2** Create a changing variable (Javascript):
    var alpha = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#beta').hide();
        $('#a').click(function() {
            $('.alpha').fadeTo('slow', alpha);
            if(alpha == 0)
            {
                alpha = 1;
            }else
            {
                alpha = 0;
            }
        });
    });

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/7/)**

I would use the first option, because it requires less code and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that flips between the two:

http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#beta').hide();
    $('#a').click(function() {
       $('#alpha').toggle(500);
       $('#beta').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's quite nice, but not the transition effect that was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a better way other than using a conditional statement:

http://jsfiddle.net/ShLqJ/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $alpha = $('#alpha'),
        $beta = $('#beta').hide();

    $('#a').click(function() {
        var $in, $out;
        if($alpha.is(':visible')) {
            $in = $beta, $out = $alpha;
        } else {
            $in = $alpha, $out = $beta;
        }

        $out.fadeOut("slow", function() {
             $in.fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery makes this really easy here is an example using `fadeToggle()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').click(function() {
        $('#alpha').fadeToggle();
        $('#beta').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

You just have to start one of the two divs with `display: hidden`.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr5Y7/)